# How to set fontWithName and italic

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, uifont

I know how to set font with using `fontWithName:` and how to set systemFont, both bold and italic.
But how do I set a font with name if I want that to be italic?

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:15];
```

or

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:15];
```

I want an italic Georgia, how?

Comment: According to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052570/how-to-set-fontwithname-and-italic/36974547#comment11373039_9052690), Lars actually wants it Italic and Bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must know the variant name, something like "GeorgiaIT" or "GeorgiaItalic".

Comment: I know this is really old, but http://iosfonts.com/ gives you a good rundown of available fonts and their variant names.

Answer (score 6):

To get it in italic you will need to do something like:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Italic" size:15];
```

Or:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"GeorgiaItalic" size:15];
```

To find out which you would be best off using :

```
NSArray *fontArray = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Georgia"];
```

And then print this in the debugger to see which subtypes are available.

To use the system font there is:

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:SIZE];
```

And:

```
[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:SIZE];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. What I really wanted was bold and italic so after some experimenting Georgia-BoldItalic worked.

Comment: you should accept the answer, since it seems it has helped you

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to play with the font names. With iOS7+, using the font descriptor you need no names:

```
// original font to modify
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:15];
// adding bold and italic descriptor
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [font.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
// making the new font; size:0 means 'keep the size as is'
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:0];
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777132/1033581)

With iOS3.2+, you can try CoreText:

```
// original font to modify
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:15];
// CoreText font equivalent
CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL);
// adding bold and italic
CTFontRef ctFont2 = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(ctFont, 0.0, NULL, kCTFontBoldTrait | kCTFontItalicTrait, kCTFontBoldTrait | kCTFontItalicTrait);
CFRelease(ctFont);
// back to UIFont
UIFont *newfont = [UIFont fontWithName:CFBridgingRelease( CTFontCopyPostScriptName(ctFont2)) size:CTFontGetSize(ctFont2)];
CFRelease(ctFont2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I solved it this way, which will yield either (1) The Italic face you're looking for (assuming it's named ...-Italic), or (2) At least the base font so things (hopefully) don't crash. Incidentally, the whole NSRange thing is so that we ignore -ItalicBold, for example, although it's usually -BoldItalic, so we'd ignore it anyway.
Cheers
-W

```
UIFont *myBaseForItalicFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontDescriptorTextStyleBody];
NSString *myFontFamilyName = myBaseForItalicFont.familyName;
NSArray *myFontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:myFontFamilyName];
for (NSString *aFontName in myFontNames)
{
    NSRange myRange = [aFontName rangeOfString:@"-Italic"];
    if (myRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        if (myRange.location + myRange.length >= aFontName.length)
        {
            // This is it! Nothing before the hyphen, nothing after.
            myBaseForItalicFont = [UIFont fontWithName:aFontName size:myRVGItalicFont.pointSize];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Cœur's answer in Swift:

```
let originalFont = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15)
// or: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
let originalFontDesc = originalFont.fontDescriptor
let italicFontDesc = originalFontDesc.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)
let italicFont = UIFont(descriptor: italicFontDesc, size: 0)
myLabel.font = italicFont
```