# UILabel font : bold and italic

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel, uifont

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set bold and italic on UILabel of iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713236/how-do-i-set-bold-and-italic-on-uilabel-of-iphone-ipad)

I am trying to make UILabel font bold and italic both using system font, but I cant use these both style at a time. so is it possible to make font bold and italic using system font? here is my code,

```
lblTitle.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

or

```
lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
```

I want my font Bold and Italic both.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713236/how-do-i-set-bold-and-italic-on-uilabel-of-iphone-ipad

Comment: oops, spelling mistake in Arial... it was Ariel :( my bad luck... you can use other fonts from the link provided.

Comment: Any one know what the System Font Bold answer is to this?  I can't find where it says, "Apple System Font is ..."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this code...

```
UIFont *yourFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" 
                                   size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
lblTitle.font = yourFont;
```

you can use also another fontName for BoldItalik like.

`Optima-BoldItalic`,`TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT`,`Baskerville-BoldItalic`,`HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic`,etc...

Answer (score 6):

There are several font that contains Bod+Italic in themselves you can use those fonts...
One frequently for an example is

```
lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldItalicMT" size:16.0f];
```

others are :

**- TrebuchetMS-Bold**

**- Helvetica-BoldOblique**

**- This [link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6000-list-uifonts-available.html) will help you.**

Comment: The first one won't do what OP wants - the 2nd call will overwrite the first and the font will be italic only.

Comment: ok, i am removing that one :)