# iOS - Is it possible to make UIFont SystemFont Italic and Thin (without using fontWithName:)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont, uifontdescriptor, uifontweighttrait

My app uses only **system fonts**, and I am creating them with function -

```
+ (UIFont * _Nonnull)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize weight:(CGFloat)weight
```

How Can I make System font Italic with weight UIFontWeightThin?

I cannot use the call for specific family font (fontWithName:) since I want it to be system fonts only.

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel font : bold and italic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019441/uilabel-font-bold-and-italic)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17977354/2268168

Comment: I don't want to use UIFont fontWithName: since I want it to be the System font (Helvetica for ios 8, SF for ios 9 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should create Font Descriptor at first that contain the type of your font if it Italic or Bold or Thin, etc..

```
UIFontDescriptor* desc = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:
                          @{
                            UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute: @"Thin"
                            }
                          ];
```

after that create a font object that hold the descriptor information

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:desc size:17];
```

So, set you font object to your label.

Now you got a font object using system font but you can change the the type and size of it without using fontWithName.

Comment: But how would you make a font with both "Thin" and "Italic" face attributes? You can't have duplicate keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @DielsonSales you can create two UIFontDescription objects, one for 'thin' and one for 'italic', and now you can create your font using whatever you want, even italic or thin.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
[youLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[youLabel.font fontName] size:UIFontWeightThin]];
```

Comment: Size is not the same thing as weight. You should not pass `UIFontWeightThin`, but should pass the size of the text to the setFont:size: method.