# Trying to get SF Pro Display Thin Italics on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an iOS app in Swift, and I want to use the system font, SF Pro. However, I can't seem to figure out how to set the font weight at the same time as making the text italic. I know this was possible with Helvetica Neue with

```
UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic", size: 24.0)
```

But when using the system font, I can only seem to do one or the other like this

```
UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 24)
```

or

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 75.0, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
```

I have seen SF Pro Display Thin Italic in Font Book, and I know you can use it in editing apps like Sketch and Photoshop, but I have yet to find a way to get iOS to display it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
    var fnt = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 75.0, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
    if let dsc = fnt.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic) {
        fnt = UIFont(descriptor: dsc, size: 0)
    }
    labelOne.font = fnt
```

That should give you something to build on - such as turning it into an `extension` to make it flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Found this extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777132/2704776)

```
extension UIFont {

func withTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits...) -> UIFont? {
    guard let descriptorL = self.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(traits)) 
    else{
        return nil
    }
    return UIFont(descriptor: descriptorL, size: 0)
}

func boldItalic() -> UIFont? {
    return withTraits(traits: .traitBold, .traitItalic)
}
```

Use the extension as:

```
label.font = label.font.boldItalic()
```

Answer (score 1):

As (an ugly) on-liner:

```
UIFont(descriptor: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .thin).fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!, size: 14)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
UIFont(name: "SanFranciscoText-LightItalic", size: 24.0)
```

In general, use this site for fonts: http://iosfonts.com/